# Google | OAuth 400 redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: php, authentication, joomla, oauth

I would like to create google authentication but can't find an error:
I have a code below:

```
$client_id = 'xxxxxxx-4bsrudsadhna5817fddlhmf02ihgrcr0.apps.googleusercontent.com'; 
$client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$redirect_uri = 'http://`localhost`/joomla/index.php?option=com_component&view=quest&task=signup'; 
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth';
$params = array(
'redirect_uri'      => $redirect_uri,
'response_type'     => 'code',
'client_id'         => $client_id,
'scope'             => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
);  

$this->google_auth_link = $url . '?' . urldecode(http_build_query($params));

echo '<a href="'.$this->google_auth_link.'">Login using Google +</a>';
```

But this returns me:

```
400 - That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

The redirect URI in the request: http://`localhost`/joomla/index.php?option=com_component did not match a registered redirect URI

P.S Seems to be this part of URI has been dropped: &view=quest&task=signup

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `urldecode` here? That makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: This is very odd but without urldecode this code works! Why?

Comment: Because only that way the parameters you are passing _are_ URL-encoded properly, which `http_build_query` takes care of - and by deliberately reverting that you are messing it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the backtick operator inside single quotes. The 3rd line should be

```
$redirect_uri = 'http://'.`localhost`.'/joomla/index.php?option=com_component&view=quest&task=signup';
```